# MassTransit message contracts microservices approach

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit

I want to create a simple microservices project using MassTransit (for the first time). My concern is about message contracts. I'm not a fan of shared projects in microservices but MassTransit forces me to put massages in one shared project or create theme in separate projects but namespace must be the same. How do you handle this requirement? Do you create shared project or create messages e.g. without a namespace?

Answer (score 2):

Either approach works, it's whatever makes you most comfortable.

If you create a shared NuGet, and ensure your contracts are evolved to retain backwards compatibility, there is no need for projects to upgrade the NuGet. So long as any contract changes are made in a way that new properties are optional/nullable, and the consumer handles missing properties appropriately, there are no concerns.

Separate contracts in each project essentially have to be managed the same way, only now you have to update multiple projects to use any of the additional properties. Maybe not a big deal, but cut-and-paste isn't exactly fun.

The namespace concern is just ridiculous in my opinion. It's a string, in a file. I don't understand why people get worked up over it, but if MassTransit only used class name for a message type identifier, it would be a mess.

Comment: Not configurable namespaces in MT are still an issue. I need to consume messages from a legacy system with a weird namespaces and it seems I have to "fake" that namespace in my consumer service (code is not sharable). I would like to be able to override it by an attribute or formatter.

Comment: Submit a reasonable proposal via a GitHub Discussion and I'll consider it.